# Can you prepare orzo coffee in a moka pot?

Tags: espresso, brewing-process

I have a Bialetti Moka Express and would like to try orzo/barley coffee.

I know they sell an orzo express model, but was wondering if I can just use my moka pot

Comment: You should remove the "espresso" tag. Moka pot does not produce espresso, not even close.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- With coffee moka, you have to fill the funnel with barley only for one half;
- Otherwise, you can use the barley model, named as [Orzo Express](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004AE1Y0C), they have the funnel shorter and you can fill entirely without problems.

Using a moka for coffee, and a different one for barley coffee, is a good practice, otherwise the taste of (ground) coffee will be highly altered.